# Covariance matrix as optimization problem solution?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics, random-matrices

I have seen the expectation of a random vector expressed as the solution to the optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X]=argmin_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n}\mathbb{E}[\|X-v\|_{l^2}^2](:= \int_{\Omega} \|X(\omega)-v\|^2 dP(\omega)).
\end{equation}

---

My question is... can we express the covariance matrix of a random vector as a similar optimization problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:
Let $X$ be zero mean. Then the covariance matrix is $  \text{cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^T]$. Hence, by the same argument:
\begin{align*}
  \text{cov}(X) = \text{arg} \min_{\Sigma} \; \mathbb{E} \| XX^T - \Sigma\|_F^2
\end{align*}
If $X$ not zero mean, let $X'$ be an independent copy. Then, $X - X'$ is zero mean an $\text{cov}(X-X') = 2 \text{cov}(X)$, hence
\begin{align*}
  \text{cov}(X) = \frac12\text{arg} \min_{\Sigma} \; \mathbb{E} \| (X-X')(X-X')^T - \Sigma\|_F^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much passerby, I'm guessing this would also work for the tensors representing the higher moments?....

Comment: No problem... Re tensors, perhaps if you are talking about tensors of central moments. You should be able to use the symmetrization trick. By the way, just double check to see if not wrong!

Comment: Yes I'll do both those things now, thanks again :)

Comment: No problem at all :) By the way, it should be argmin, not argmax.

Comment: Right, my bad; late night typo on my part it seems...